# how can use grep to pull out a string from a file

Tags: regex, bash, expression

I'm trying to use grep to pull out the string "apples1" which is found in a text file name test.txt
Note the string appples1 can be of different amounts of characters or a different name. How can grep pull out that string only, regardless of its number of characters? I don't need what follows after the -.

Below is what's found in the file

```
order = ["apples1-0548-tm00", "testme2-0548-tm01"]
```

I've tried the following command, but it does not give me any output.

```
cat test.txt |grep 'order' |awk '{print $3}' | tr -d \[:punct:] | cut -c 1-7
```

Comment: If it can be different lengths and a different name, what is the criteria for what you want to extract?

Comment: Is it always the first word after `["`?

Comment: Hi, barmar that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with `sed` for that. First delete the dash and everything following it, then delete everything up to and including a double quote:

```
sed 's/-.*// ; s/.*"//' test.txt
apples1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk` and specify the field separator to be either `["` or `-`. Then extract the second field.

```
awk -F'\\["|-' '/order/ {print $2}' test.txt
```